# Send XML file to Web Service using Java

Tags: web-services, xmlhttprequest

I want to send an XML file to a Web Service. 
The Web Service is a java application.
I know the endpoint of the Web Service.
Typically I know I have to create the request and send it as an http/https request.

What I want to know is what would I have to make to send the request - as in what development tool could I use e.g. Visual Web Developer (preffered as I am familiar with this) or Visual Studio? And what sends the request - e.g. another Web Service, a Website etc?

Where do I even begin with this?

Any comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't these .net IDE's and your tagging it as JAVA

Comment: There seems to be a couple of elements to this question. When you ask for "what would I have to make to send the request - as in what development tool could I use", are you looking for a GUI tool for sending XML requests to a Web Service? Normally I would suggest an API  but your example is Visual Web Developer. I'm not quite sure what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dunderklumpen - Sorry for being vague, my problem is, I want to create a client application for the web service to send XML files and get a response from the web service. Do I do this with a web page or another method, and would I use VWD to create the client? Then use a GUI? I'm rather lost but thanks for your response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I even begin with this?

One purpose of a Webservice is loose coupling. So it depends on what you want to do. You can write a simple program in what ever language which constructs a request and sends it. You can write a Webservice on its own which uses the other Webservice to handle it's own requests. 
You can handle this in a very simple or complex way. You only need to be able to generate a request (per xml) and send it.

Comment: Hi kasten, thanks for your response. All  need to do is get the XML file from A to B. My problem is I know that "B" is the web service. I want to create "A". Can you suggest where I start and what tool to do it in? I have made a web service in Visual Web Developer that was linked to a website that showed specific results. Perhaps I could build on this? Thanks.

Comment: From where should "A" send? Your own PC, a webserver, or a smartphone? I don't know Visula Web Deveoper but i think that you can create your request when someone calls a certain webpage.

Comment: @Lambo you can create a webservice that accepts byte array as request then from ws client you can make request of sending file to server and at server side you can re generate file from sent byte array, There is better solution is spring webservice and you can create client classes from wsdl , to make request there is a tool called `SOAPUI`

Comment: In response to kasten, I would be sending the XML from my PC, to a web service. However I wish to test it before I put it into use.Once the XML has beed sent to the Web Service I would require an aknowledgement or error message. Thanks for the info on the web page Im sure I can do this in VWD. Any other info you would suggest would be appreciated.

Comment: @org.life.XML thakns for your time I have had a look at spring webservice however am completely unfamilliar with it. Would you suggest using this over and Microsoft software?

Comment: @Lambo - Try to find the specification of the Webservice. It should send you a response.